# Search for immediate selector in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which accepts `obj` (Jq object) as a parameter

However  , in this function , I **only need** `obj` which is  `:not(:disabled)` and `:not([readonly]`

currently I've managed to do it with :

```
function CheckRequiredSelection(obj)
{
    obj.find(".requiredSelection:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])").andSelf().each(function ()
    {
...
    });

}
```

But I really want to get rid of `find` and `addSelf` trick.

Any help ?

The document can contain :

Edit #1
    
    ...

```
<select class="requiredSelection">
...
</select>

<select class="requiredSelection">
...
</select>
```

and before submit :  I do something like :

`CheckRequiredSelection($(".requiredSelection"))`

Edit #2

I could have check inside the .each loop but then it wont be efficient since it's after the selector. ( instead of getting 5 filtered elements from 100 , I will get 100 elements and THEN i'll have to filter. That's not nice).

Comment: Do you have control over how you select the jQ object you pass in?

Comment: @ElliotBonneville look at my edit. I only know I need to "take care" of  `$(".requiredSelection")` but I want the function to handle only obj which is not... and not...

Comment: I really dont get your question entirely but I guess you are looking for [is](http://api.jquery.com/is) `obj.is(".requiredSelection:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])")`

Comment: @Jashwant  I'm building my own validation plugin based on classes. How would I use your solution with each ?  the filter looks better cause it filter before the loop. your solution will have to check each time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
function CheckRequiredSelection(obj)
{
    obj.filter(":visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])").each(function ()
    {
...
    });

}
```

Comment: I know the filter function. is it the fastest solution ( in jQ scope) ?

Comment: Also I think you should remove `.requiredSelection` inside the filter.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I think 100 elements are not a trouble to jQuery. And `filter` is easier to read.

Comment: I dont care about reading.  is it the fastest solution ( in jQ scope)  ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I really don't know, you can make a test. But I think for 100 elements, there will be not much difference.

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil" - Donald Knuth. Take heed.

Comment: @Bojangles, take my appreciation. You just touched one of my worst coding practices.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [is](http://api.jquery.com/is)

> Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element,
>   or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements
>   matches the given arguments.

So, your code will look like,

```
function CheckRequiredSelection(obj) {
    obj.is(".requiredSelection:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])")
}
```

I am not sure if its faster than `filter` or not.

But `is` is there to be used in such situations.

You can test the performance at [jsperf](http://www.jsperf.com)

Comment: How would I use your solution with each

Comment: `is` returns `true` / `false`. Why do you need `.each` ? If `obj` is an array of `objects`, then you can always loop through it. like `obj.each(function () { if($(this).is(".requiredSelection:visible:not(:disabled):not([readonly])")) { //Your logic })`